# What is another word for someone who takes out their pain on someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests

A person who takes things out on other people. They let out what they're going through on others who don't deserve it.  Not just anger or violence. Any negative emotion of sadness, fear, loneliness, insecurities, past experiences, past treatments from others..

Comment: *Vindictive*, perhaps?

Comment: I thought so too, but some dictionaries point out that its means taking it out on someone who has harmed them. My focus is for the question is on the fact they take it out on others who didn't deserve it or were not responsible for it.

Comment: Had an uncle like that... We used to just call him a "moody a-hole." US

Comment: What you have described is an *angry person* -- angry at the world. Lots of hits if you google it.

Comment: I would say"jerk".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bully. Bully is all that comes to my mind. You were looking for a noun, specifically one that is descriptive. A bully is a domineering person, who in this day and age usually is one because of things they went through. You can look up synonyms, but the best word is bully.

Comment: A bully is not motivated by the bad treatment of which he is the victim.

Answer (score 0):

The term "scapegoating" is the non specialist term that comes closest to describing this sort of behaviour but it is not good enough; there lacks this essential element: a scapegoat is invariably explicitly (and perversely) accused of a fault they are not responsible for. In the case examined in the OP's question the behaviour  is grounded in an obscure perverse motivation that only psychologists might try to identify: there is no telling what goes on in somebody's mind pushed to this type of behaviour and it might have to be considered rather as the result of a psychological affliction rather than as amoral behaviour.   This behaviour is a form of psychological projection ([projection](https://www.everydayhealth.com/emotional-health/psychological-projection-dealing-with-undesirable-emotions/), [displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(psychology))).
There is no single word for this type of person. A two word term could be "**displaced aggressor**" from the behaviour termed "displaced aggression" ([displaced aggression](https://study.com/academy/lesson/displaced-aggression-definition-theory.html)), a term used in psychology; However, it's not a term in use and you'd have to use it between  quotes.

*Some non identified source*

*Displaced aggression is aggression that cannot be expressed to the actual source that provoked the behavior. Instead, the anger is released onto someone who had nothing to do with the original conflict.*

Answer (score 0):

Best answer(and atleast much better than bully(which shows intention to be bully)) for this(atleast for now) case would is ["person with misplaced anger" or "one with displaced aggression"](https://www.google.com/search?q=one%20word%20for%20taking%20out%20anger%20on%20someone%20else%20innocent).

It still doesn't include other emotions, for those, we might just have wait for English to become more evolved. Or just someone to loanword from other language that might just have it.

But for now we'd have to do with "displaced aggressor" or "wrongful aggressor" for the one who takes out anger/wrath w/ or w/o violence on someone innocent or atleast unrelated.